# How to build a template for mapserver?

Tags: mapserver, template, user-interface

I'm working on a project using MapServer and I'm having trouble to build my html template.

Comment: Which templating system or framework are you using?

Comment: I'm not avoiding code, what I want to do is a template that works, because everything I read on internet lead me to something that does not works.

Comment: Then take a look at OpenLayers or Leaflet and read some tutorials where you could copy an example. Start from there. These are very solid libraries. If it doesn't work, chances are that you are doing things wrong.

Comment: I've tried OpenLayers, doesn't work for me. For now, I have shapefiles to use to render my map, and I wasn't able to find wherer I could put it to test. And according to the documentation of the project, these tools are not an Option

Answer (score 2):

There is no user interface for MapServer. You need to create your own or use some wrapper like NextGIS Web. See: http://docs.nextgis.com/docs_ngweb/source/mapstyles.html

You can try this functionality on http://nextgis.com/ or install [NextGIS Web + nextgisweb_mapserver extension](https://github.com/nextgis/nextgisweb_mapserver) on your own server.

[image]

Comment: I'm not looking for something like this. I'm just looking for a simple method to build my template and work on it. My template does not work, and some exemples from map server uses something like I'm use and works, but somehow mine does not.

Answer (score 2):

Mapserver is only pushing cartographic web services (WMS, WFS, etc.). These become you data source that you show on a map.

The web map can be built using a wrapper like NextGIS Web (as suggested by user Dmitry Baryshnikov) or Mapbender, etc. You can even use these services is QGIS or ArcMap.

You can build a web maps from scratch using HTML/CSS and Javascript libraries like OpenLayers or Leaflet and use the WMS/WFS services pushed by you Mapserver as a datasource. There are also a few tools out there that can help you build a map without coding anyting.

I use Mapbender in my organization to create web map applications. I also use Mapserver to push WMS/WFS services.

Comment: I've tried to render my maps using MapBender before, does not work.

Comment: Then it must be your Mapserver or something. Mapbender works pretty good.

Comment: MapServer here is working, but I am not able to build a template who actually works as I need. The demo-map of map server has something similar what I need, but even following these files my template does not work.